# 2013 Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Database Administrators' [third moderator election](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Aaron Bertrand]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/1579040/0).

Comment: I guess congratulations are in order. Horray to the new mod!

Comment: Congrats @Aaron Bertrand! And thanks for posting this where it is more visible to community members.

Comment: Congrats @Aaron Bertrand. Happy Modding. :)

Comment: Congrats from @RolandoMySQLDBA